# SharePoint 2013 gridview

Tags: 2013, spgridview

[image]

The new SharePoint 2013 gridview is really cool (see above). I like to use it in an application page since I need to add some extra functionality to it (preview and copy to clipboard).
Is there any guide on how to leverage this really cool control on an application page?. I tried creating it based on the SharePoint 2010 spgridview and added the css jsgrid but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, actually that control is the upgraded version of the SPGridView (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spgridview.aspx). You should be able to use the same SHarePoint 2010 examples, many available

- http://www.srinisistla.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=129
- http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2010/10/spgridview-explained.html
- http://sharepointcafe.net/forum_view/131-SharePoint-search-result-display-in-a-Gridview

Comment: Thanks Marius, I'm a big fan of SPGridView. Used it all the time when it comes to displaying data due to its sorting paging and filtering functionality that available almost automatically (SPGridView + LinqDataSource). The 2013 version of this control is not the same as the 2010. There are more items involves in term of css and javascript in order to make it the way it is in the 2013. Try look into the Script section of the IE developer tools when the control is displaying and you'll see the differences. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are absolutely right, so many have been improved/added to every control in SPS 2013, particularly with regards to client-side features. Server-side should function the same - which would get you the expected results when rendered. You should maybe consider also the Client-Side Rendering technique to generate grid-like behavior quickly without actual "development" (compiled code)

Comment: Agamand, do you have an example of where you implemented the SPGridView successfully with all the Javascript additions? I've been researching this topic for a while and your question is the closest I've come to an answer. I only need the step for the Javascript implementation as I've got the SPGridView control working successfully on the server side.